# Accessing ToolKitScriptManager/ScriptManager from custom control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm writing a custom class library that contains custom controls (not user controls).
I have some embedded javascript files that need to be registered on the page.

Now since this is a class library, how do I detect whether or not to use a ToolKitScriptManager or ScriptManager?

Page.ClientScript is a ClientScriptManager, but would I do if the page has the new ToolKitScriptManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine if the page your control is being instantiated in is using a `ScriptManager` by calling the static [`ScriptManager.GetCurrent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.getcurrent.aspx) method. If this returns `null` then you could assume that (working on the basis that your controls will only be used within your websites), the page is utilising a `ToolKitScriptManager` rather than a `ScriptManager`.

Comment: Assuming that the page utilizes a ToolKitScriptManager and the method returns null, then what is the most effective way to find the ToolKitScriptManager? Loop through the pages controls until I find it?

Comment: Given that `ToolKitScriptManager` derives from `ScriptManager` I'd suspect that calling `ScriptManager.GetCurrent` would return (for a page that contains a ToolKitScriptManager) a reference to ToolKitScriptManager (for a page that contains one, cast as a ScriptManager) or a reference to a ScriptManager, so if either is on the page you shouldn't get `null` returned...

Comment: Your suspicions are correct.  I also note that I found that `ScriptManager` handed me the `ToolScriptManager` instance.  To use your code, it is potentially necessary to use the namespace explicitly (e.g., calling `System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);`).