# Postback via update panel resets TabIndex?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866026/tab-index-stops-working-after-selecting-value-from-dropdownlist-in-asp-net) is the only related post I've found so far on SO, not my exact issue, but close.

If I give focus to the first textbox on my page and then press TAB repeatedly until I reach the last control on my page the tab order works flawlessly, every control is given focus in the correct order.

BUT...

If I am actually filling out the form and I select a value in ANY dropdownlist, when I press TAB after selecting the value focus is given to the first textbox on my page rather than the next control after said dropdownlist.

I created a control that includes a label, a dropdownlist and an imagebutton because this list is used multiple times throughout my application.  The control looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OrganizationList.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyApp.Web.Controls.OrganizationList" %>
<%@ Register src="UpdateProgress.ascx" tagname="UpdateProgress" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register src="Address.ascx" tagname="Address" tagprefix="uc2" %>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="OrganizationUpdatePanel" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <div style="margin: 0px;">
            <div class="label"><asp:Label ID="Prompt" runat="server"></asp:Label>:</div>
            <div class="field"><asp:DropDownList ID="Organizations" runat="server" Width="205" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id"></asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;<asp:ImageButton id="AddOrganization" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ToolTip="Add a new organization" onclick="AddOrganization_Click" /></div>
        </div>

        <asp:HiddenField ID="DummyButton" runat="server" />
        <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="AddOrganizationModalPopupExtender" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="Cancel" DropShadow="true" PopupControlID="NewOrganization" RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll" TargetControlID="DummyButton"></ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="NewOrganization" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopUp" Width="500">
            <asp:Panel ID="OrganizationModalContent" runat="server" CssClass="modalContent" GroupingText="Add Organization" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top;" Width="490">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr><td colspan="2"><asp:ValidationSummary ID="OrganizationValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="ValidationSummary" ValidationGroup="NewOrg" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="label"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Name" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please provide the organization's name." SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="NewOrg">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>Organization Name:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" MaxLength="100" Width="200"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="label"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PhoneRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Phone" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please provide the organization's phone number." SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="NewOrg">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>Phone:</td>
                        <td><ajax:MaskedEditExtender ID="PhoneMaskedEditExtender" runat="server" ClearTextOnInvalid="true" InputDirection="LeftToRight" Mask="(999)999-9999" MaskType="Number" MessageValidatorTip="true" PromptCharacter="_" TargetControlID="Phone"></ajax:MaskedEditExtender>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Phone" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Width="200"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="label">Fax:<br />(optional)</td>
                        <td><ajax:MaskedEditExtender ID="FaxMaskedEditExtender" runat="server" ClearTextOnInvalid="true" InputDirection="LeftToRight" Mask="(999)999-9999" MaskType="Number" MessageValidatorTip="true" PromptCharacter="_" TargetControlID="Fax"></ajax:MaskedEditExtender>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Fax" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Width="200"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2"><uc2:Address ID="Address" runat="server" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;"><asp:HiddenField ID="TypeOfList" runat="server" /><asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" Text="Submit" onclick="Submit_Click" ValidationGroup="NewOrg" /><asp:Button ID="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<uc1:UpdateProgress ID="OrganizationUpdateProgress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelId="OrganizationUpdatePanel" />
```

Here's the TabIndex property on my control:

```
public short TabIndex
{
    get { return Organizations.TabIndex; }
    set { Organizations.TabIndex = value; AddOrganization.TabIndex = (short)(value + 1); }
}
```

Here's one of the references to the control on the parent page:

```
<uc3:OrganizationList ID="ReportedBy" runat="server" FieldLabel="Reported By" ListType="ReportedBy" TabIndex="105" />
```

Not sure what else you might want/need to see.

Browsers: IE8, IE9, IE10, FF 29.0.1

We've had some issues with IE versions above 9, so I added a HTTP Response Header to emulate IE9

[image]

My users claim that they primarily TAB to navigate in my app, so this is actually a higher priority bug than I expected.  I don't know why the TabIndex is ignored once a value is selected.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I do have 1 dropdownlist that is just an out-of-the-box dropdownlist, not a user control.  That one works correctly.  I can select a value in that list and then press TAB and the focus moves to the next control.  So, can anyone help me figure out what is "wrong" with my user control that is causing this bug?

Comment: have you looked at any of the other TabIndexes you must have more set if that TabIndex is `105`

Comment: I went through the ENTIRE page 3 times last week Friday and fixed all of the tab indexes because the tabbing was all messed up after a recent change.  This tabbing bug went from being classified as a low priority annoyance to being something that MUST work correctly overnight. (????)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two posts helped me figure out what I needed to do:

- [A postback via update panel resets TabIndex?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1069828.aspx?A%20postback%20via%20update%20panel%20resets%20TabIndex%20)
- [Accessing ToolKitScriptManager/ScriptManager from custom control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432360/accessing-toolkitscriptmanager-scriptmanager-from-custom-control)

I added a SelectedIndexChanged event handler to my DropDownList in my control and set the focus back to the DropDownList.  Here's the code:

```
protected void Organizations_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    ScriptManager scriptMgr = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
    scriptMgr.SetFocus(ddl);
}
```

Here's the control on the .aspx page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Organizations" runat="server" Width="205" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Organizations_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**2014.05.22 UPDATE:**

In my custom control I have an image button (+) named AddOrganization.  In testing the fix yesterday we discovered that if a user clicked the '+' to add a new organization...after they saved the organization...the new value would get auto-selected (as expected) but the tabbing would get reset again.  So I had to modify my button click event handler:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        // Do stuff...save organization

        // update the list
        BindOrganizationList();
        // select the new value
        Organizations.SelectedIndex = Organizations.Items.IndexOf(Organizations.Items.FindByText(OrganizationName.Text.ToUpper().Trim()));
        // reset the form
        ResetOrganizationForm();
        OrganizationUpdatePanel.Update();
        // set focus back to the dropdownlist
        ScriptManager scriptMgr = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
        scriptMgr.SetFocus(Organizations);
    }
    else
    {
        // Display friendly validation messages to user
    }
}
```